# How to restore an accidentally deleted keyboard shortcut from a VSCode extension?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I was configuring [PostgreSQL](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ckolkman.vscode-postgres) VSCode extension and when customizing some keyboards shortcuts, I excluded an essencial functionality of querying database through <kbd>F5</kbd>. It seems to be accessible only through this shortcut, and in `settings.json` I didn't see anything regarding to it.

(It's supposed to show F5 shortcut in first result)

[image: It's supposed to show F5 shortcut in first result]

Not sure if it is something related to this extension specifically, but even if I **reinstalled** it and **reloaded** VSCode, the mentioned shortcut won't show up. I think my configuration is cached somewhere (I wonder where). How can I **restore** it?

Comment: if it was a key binding than there has to be a command that has the functionality, if the binding is defined in the extension you can't loose/delete it, than probably you have defined another command to F5, view/delete/save your keybinding.json or use the key binding debugging, see key binding doc page

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If it was a key binding than there has to be a command that has the functionality. Most likely that command can also be accessed from the Command Palette. Or you can find the commands exported by the extension on the `Feature Contributions` tab of the extensions page (Extension Bar)

If the binding is defined in the extension you can't loose/delete it, than probably you have defined another command to F5.

View/Delete/Save your `keybinding.json` or use the [key binding debugging](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/keybindings#_troubleshooting-keybindings)

Comment: Thanks. I've posted another question about vscode, if you can help me I'd be grateful

Comment: @testing_22 A link might be useful, it is shown under the question

Answer (score 0):

I resolve this problem delete some files:

```
rm -rf ~/.config/Code/User/globalStorage 
rm ~/.config/Code/User/keybindings.json
```

Now you can open your vscode, and your keyboard settings was restarted